# Prove that for every natural $n\geq6$, the set $\{n+1,\cdots, n+30\}$ contains no more than eight prime numbers using inclusion-exclusion principle.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, inclusion-exclusion

Honestly, I have no idea how to prove that but I noticed that if we try to find the number of coprimes with $30$ that are less than $30$, we will get $22$ numbers that are not coprime using the exclusion inclusion principle and then $30 - 22 = 8$ coprimes.

Is this related somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure the inclusion exclusion principle is relevant here, other than proving $\phi(30)=8$. Your proof strategy is just to prove that at most $8$ in your set can be coprime to $30$.

Comment: If you understand Italian, here is a paper that we wrote years ago about this question, just by replacing $n+30$ with $n+100$: https://www.matematicamente.it/magazine/25ottobre2015/228-Quanti-numeri-primi-in-100-interi-consecutivi.pdf

Comment: P.S. In order to answer you question properly, you can simply apply the approach described in the above mentioned paper. It works fine also for $n+30$ instead of $n+100$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the set $S=\{2,3,5\}$ of primes. By inclusion–exclusion, the count of integers in $[n+1,n+30]$ that are coprime to all primes in $S$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{P\subset S}(-1)^{|P|}\frac{30}{\prod_{p\in P}p}
&=&
\frac{30}1-\frac{30}2-\frac{30}3-\frac{30}5+\frac{30}{2\cdot3}+\frac{30}{5\cdot2}+\frac{30}{3\cdot5}-\frac{30}{2\cdot3\cdot5}
\\
&=&
30-15-10-6+5+3+2-1
\\
&=&8\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Why does it work? Because an arbitrary set of 30 consecutive natural numbers necessarily contains 30/2 numbers divisible by 2, 30/3 numbers divisible by 3, and so on?

Comment: (+1)@user492754 the method works as follows: from $30$, subtract the number of elements divisible by $2$, $3$ or $5$, add back those divisible by $6$, $10$ or $15$ since you subtracted them twice, and add those divisible by $30$ since you originally subtracted it thrice but added it thrice again.

Comment: @user492754 an arbitrary set of 30 consecutive numbers _necessarily_ contains $30/2$ elements divisible by $2$, $30/3$ divisible by $3$ and $30/5$ divisible by $5$ **since** $2$, $3$ and $5$ divide $30$.

Answer (score 1):

A method without using Inclusion-Exclusion would be as follows:
Notice that if you take the elements of the set modulo $30$, you will get values $0$ to $29$. Of these, $\phi(30) = 8$ elements are not divisible by $2,3,5$. (That is: $1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29 \pmod {30}$). Whatever the value of $n$, the other $22$ elements are divisible by 2,3 and/or 5, so they are composite since $n \ge 6$. Thus, these $8$ elemnts are potential candidates of primes (of course, they may be divisible by a prime $p > 5$). Thus, the given set contains no more than $8$ primes.